# String name set to a number of characters

Tags: java

How can you make the first 4 characters of a course name FOOD, using error checking?

If not course name should be updated to error and error message displayed.

I tried this.

```
 if(!courseName.matches("FOOD") ){

         throw new IllegalArgumentException("ERROR");
    }
```

Comment: Could you be a little more clear?

Comment: Using error checking, I have a string courseName and i need to make the first four characters of it to be FOOD. If not an error message should appear.

Comment: You showed us what you tried, but you haven't told us why that doesn't work for you.  What, exactly, are you trying to do? How is your code not doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Where should the error message appear?

If in console, just log it to console:

```
if(!courseName.startsWith("FOOD")){
   //Coursename didn't start with food, log error to console
    System.err.println("Course name should start with food!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to compare the strings and if they are not equal,then throw the exception...

This might help you!!!

```
if(!courseName.equals("FOOD") ){

         throw new IllegalArgumentException("ERROR");
    }
```